# Encryption of external HDD -- accessible from windows without installation

Tags: disk-encryption, cross-platform, portable-apps, portable-harddrive

I would like to use encryption on my external HDD but I would like to be able to access the encrypted data from Windows as well. As suggested in other questions, TrueCrypt is one option here, or I am using momentarily encfs, which is not available for Windows.

But my question goes further: I would like to be able to access the encrypted partition from Windows **without installation** as I will be using it from different Windows machines for which I have no administrator access. My main OS is Linux and I have full root access to that computer.

Is there a full disk or file based encryption which I can use cross platform and which does not require installation under Windows?

ADDITION:

It seems that TrueCrypt provides a portable mode which fulfills my requirements partly: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable, but still the TrueCrypt driver needs to be installed by an administrator... pitty

Thanks

Comment: The only encryption included in the OS is Windows NT file encryption. Note that if you're using it on machines you don't own, any solution will enable the machine's administrator to steal your key when you type it in.

Comment: True - but the machines would be in the University and the same problem would aply if I could install something on them. --- What I was actually thinking about under windows is not real time encryption, but a file manager type program which is doing the encryption / decryption and allows me to copy files from and to the external hdd, which can run stand-alone from the external hdd.

Comment: BitLocker works if every machine is Windows 7.  Of course in that case it doesn't work with Linux.